# How can I include TypeScript generated .js files in TFS source control?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I don't want to do a build all typescript files on build/run.  I just want to build them on save.  However, the generated .js files are not checked in to TFS, which means another developer would have to open and save new/modified .ts files.   Is there a way to include the generated .js files in TFS?

I am using VS 2010 so I do not have the Web Essentials 2012 extension.

Comment: I usually add all the generated JavaScript files to TFS, You can do that like how you add other files. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am talking about having them included automatically, similar to the behavior for aspx designer files.  As a dependent file, I would think the behavior would be to include it in TFS.

Comment: I haven't done any TypeScript development with VS 2010, but VS 2012 behaves as aspx designer files. If you really want to see it as a dependent item, edit the project file and add a "Content" entry with DepentUpOn element inside it. e.g. <Content Include="app.js"><DependentUpon>app.ts</DependentUpon></Content>

Comment: @Rajeesh the .JS files are already dependents and included in the project.

Comment: I'm using VS2013 with TypeScript and they have made the same mistake by emitting .JS files to the folder but not including them in the source control. This means that a web project will reference .js files which won't appear in the solution folder. As much as Boris thinks these are equivalent to .exe, they are not. JS is still source, even if it's compiled from another source. My LINQ datacontext is generated code from a DBML, but that's checked into TFS.

Comment: They only just resolved TFS integration problems in VS 2013 with release 2, so I doubt those fixes will make it all the way back to VS 2010. Given the fully integrated TypeScript debugging (very productive), I would strongly suggest now is the time to upgrade to VS 3013 *if possible*.

Comment: VS2013 with update 3 seems to have fixed this. You can have the .js file in source control now and it will auto-checkout.

Comment: @Quango - yes but what happens when you do a build or rebuild when the .ts and .js files are checked in.  Don't you still get an error?

Comment: No, no error - it checks out the .js, compiles and checks back in.. I watched it in the solution window!

Comment: Is there any (new) plugin for Visual Studio 2015/17 to add generated files to source control or to project (DependUpOn file) control automatically? I am using TypeScript 2.4.1. In the TypeScript forum I found a post stating that such behavior is not the responsibility of the compiler, so I guess it only works with a third-party extension for VS?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've used was to create a blank .js file with the expected output name in your solution and check that into TFS.